# Need advice on a dynamic excel lookup

Tags: excel

I need to first search row 1 for a unique value, then once I find that value, I need to search the entirety of the column it sits in for another unique value. The unique values in the columns do not all sit in the same row. Any advice?

[Excel Example Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oc4g.png)

Comment: What result then do you expect? Can you put another screenshot with your desired result. Also post data as text table so that we can copy and paste to our sheet for analysis.

Comment: The desired result would just be pulling the unique ID out of each column

Comment: In case of attached screenshot what would be output? Column headings or `unique id`?

Comment: It would be the unique ID within the columns (not the header obviously)

Comment: Give a try on this formula `=FILTER(TOCOL(A2:E1000,1),TOCOL(A2:E1000,1)="unique id")`

Comment: Index() with match() for column and match() for row.